# Quickbooks qbmxl report request hangs for only one customer

Tags: web-services, quickbooks, qbxml

I have a integrated application via webconnector that is working perfectly for about 20 customers. It adds customers, vendors and updates AP and AR and receives payments without a hitch for **all** of my customers.

My application also requests AP and AR agings from QB and it works for all except one customer. I've been able to copy their file and recreate the problem in the lab. I've included the XML request and the quickbooks log. Any help, advice, clues, etc would be welcomed.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="5.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <AgingReportQueryRq>
            <!-- AgingReportType may have one of the following values: APAgingDetail, APAgingSummary, ARAgingDetail, ARAgingSummary, CollectionsReport -->
            <AgingReportType >APAgingDetail</AgingReportType>
            <ReportPeriod>
                <FromReportDate >2013-02-01</FromReportDate>
                <ToReportDate >2013-02-28</ToReportDate>
            </ReportPeriod>
            <IncludeColumn >Name</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>RefNumber</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>Date</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>OpenBalance</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>Memo</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>Account</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>NameAccountNumber</IncludeColumn>
            <IncludeColumn>TxnID</IncludeColumn>
        </AgingReportQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The log is :

```
Log file initialized at Wednesday, February 27, 2013 - 12:15 AM UTC  
Timestamp format used: YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS UTC
QBWebConnector 2.0 has been initialized with its logging status to level = VERBOSE.
Please restart QBWebConnector for any change in log level to take effect. Use file menu to clear log.

20130227.00:15:06 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""
20130227.00:15:06 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""
20130227.00:15:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed
Error message: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket, String response, String hresult, String message)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket, String response, String hresult, String message, Boolean& success, Boolean& timeout)
Source = System.Web.Services
20130227.00:15:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_CompanyQueryRqXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="10.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><CompanyQueryRq requestID="1"><OwnerID>{ADB06C95-6FC7-4D8D-AC30-6A28E24AAB22}</OwnerID></CompanyQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>

20130227.00:15:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_CompanyQueryRqXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<CompanyQueryRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
<CompanyRet>
<IsSampleCompany>false</IsSampleCompany>
<CompanyName>DFW JAVV BUS INC</CompanyName>
<LegalCompanyName>DFW JAVV BUS INC</LegalCompanyName>
<Address>
<Addr1>105 101TH Street #501</Addr1>
<City>Little Prairie</City>
<State>CA</State>
<PostalCode>95050</PostalCode>
<Country>US</Country>
</Address>
<AddressBlock>
<Addr1>105 108TH Street #501</Addr1>
<Addr2>Little Prairie, CS  95050</Addr2>
</AddressBlock>
<LegalAddress>
<Addr1>1010 A N Davis Dr</Addr1>
<City>Lomita</City>
<State>CA</State>
<PostalCode>96012</PostalCode>
<Country>US</Country>
</LegalAddress>
<Phone>972-522-1500</Phone>
<FirstMonthFiscalYear>January</FirstMonthFiscalYear>
<FirstMonthIncomeTaxYear>January</FirstMonthIncomeTaxYear>
<CompanyType>other</CompanyType>
<EIN>20-3726264</EIN>
<TaxForm>Form1120S</TaxForm>
<SubscribedServices>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Online Banking</Name>
<Domain>banking.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Online Billing</Name>
<Domain>billing.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Level 1 Service</Name>
<Domain>qbob1.qbn</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Level 2 Service</Name>
<Domain>qbob2.qbn</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Payment Service</Name>
<Domain>qbobpay.qbn</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Bill Payment</Name>
<Domain>billpay.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Online Billing Paper Mailing Service</Name>
<Domain>qbobpaper.qbn</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Payroll Service</Name>
<Domain>payroll.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Basic Payroll Service</Name>
<Domain>payrollbsc.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Basic Disk Payroll Service</Name>
<Domain>payrollbscdisk.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Deluxe Payroll Service</Name>
<Domain>payrolldlx.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>QuickBooks Premier Payroll Service</Name>
<Domain>payrollprm.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>Basic Plus Federal</Name>
<Domain>basic_plus_fed.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>Basic Plus Federal and State</Name>
<Domain>basic_plus_fed_state.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>Basic Plus Direct Deposit</Name>
<Domain>basic_plus_dd.qb</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
<Service>
<Name>Merchant Account Service</Name>
<Domain>mas.qbn</Domain>
<ServiceStatus>Never</ServiceStatus>
</Service>
</SubscribedServices>
<AccountantCopy>
<AccountantCopyExists>false</AccountantCopyExists>
</AccountantCopy>
<DataExtRet>
<OwnerID>{ADB06C95-6FC7-4D8D-AC30-6A28E24AAB22}</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName>
<DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>
<DataExtValue>LOCKED:QAXP1JV_VM:634975201418013380</DataExtValue>
</DataExtRet>
<DataExtRet>
<OwnerID>{ADB06C95-6FC7-4D8D-AC30-6A28E24AAB22}</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>FileID</DataExtName>
<DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>
<DataExtValue>{714E8016-F6D4-4530-AFC3-995A34F3F7CE}</DataExtValue>
</DataExtRet>
</CompanyRet>
</CompanyQueryRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>


20130227.00:15:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.getLock() : Got Lock = LOCKED:QAXP1JV_VM:634975201418013380
20130227.00:15:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtModRqXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0"?><?qbxml version="10.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><DataExtModRq requestID="1"><DataExtMod><OwnerID>{ADB06C95-6FC7-4D8D-AC30-6A28E24AAB22}</OwnerID><DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName><OtherDataExtType>Company</OtherDataExtType><DataExtValue>UNLOCKED:QAXP1JV_VM</DataExtValue></DataExtMod></DataExtModRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>

20130227.00:15:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtModRqXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<DataExtModRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
<DataExtRet>
<OwnerID>{ADB06C95-6FC7-4D8D-AC30-6A28E24AAB22}</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>AppLock</DataExtName>
<DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>
<DataExtValue>UNLOCKED:QAXP1JV_VM</DataExtValue>
</DataExtRet>
</DataExtModRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>


20130227.00:15:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.unsetLock() : Company file has been unlocked for ownerID = <{ADB06C95-6FC7-4D8D-AC30-6A28E24AAB22}>
20130227.00:15:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.update() : Company file has been unlocked.
20130227.00:15:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.update() : Ending session to QuickBooks.
20130227.00:15:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : Session ended and connection closed
20130227.00:15:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_closeConnection() : *** Calling closeConnection() with following parameter:<wcTicket="03dfdb40-3588-4d1b-b51f-000b3d2de071">
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_closeConnection() : Received from closeConnection() following parameter:<ccResponse="OK">
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_closeConnection() : CloseConnection called to application.
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_closeConnection() : Response received from application = OK
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.update() : update completed.
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update for application = 'jvQBWebSyncApplication' has COMPLETED
20130227.00:15:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update session has ended.
```

Answer (score 3):

Why is your web server returning a 404 Not Found error?

> 20130227.00:15:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : QBWC1042:
>   ReceiveResponseXML failed Error message: The request failed with HTTP
>   status 404: Not Found. More info:

Also, you should post an entire log - this only shows the response, where's the request?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought the 404 was coming from QB since the webconnector only showed "Sending request to QB" while it was hanging and I did not catch any response from QB in my code until the close connection event.  I will dig a little further and see if I see anything in my code. I will post my results in the morning.

Comment: The 404 is coming from your web service. QuickBooks doesn't speak HTTP at all.